# Is Substrate actively published on crates.io

Tags: releases, crates-io

I know for a while after Substrate 2.0 came out, there were occasional releases on crates.io. I thought that practice had stopped and been replaced with git annotations of two different varieties

- Monthly Substrate release tags like: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/releases/tag/monthly-2022-05
- Substrate releases branches to Polkadot releases like: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.22

But today I noticed, some of the crate published on crates.io are up to higher version numbers. For example [sp-core](https://crates.io/crates/sp-core) is up to 6.0.0.

So is Substrate still being published on crates.io? And if so, can I use the latest version of each package and expect them to be compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Previous answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2817/116) which was true at time of writing 2022 but is obsolete now.*

Yes, since the release of [polkadot-sdk](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/) releases have been pushed to crates.io from a branch named `release-crates-io-v1.x.0`. It is branched from the release tag `polkadot-v1.x.0`.

There is no correlation between the version numbers on crates.io and the github tag, so some manual investigation of the versions are required.

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment. There's *a lot* of crates in substrate. For now monthly branches are created and branches for each polkadot version as you have observed. I think using those are the best option. That said a small subset of crates are published on a regular basis, for example https://crates.io/crates/ss58-registry .